# JQuery and select2 selector reference

Tags: jquery, reference, jquery-select2

Lets say I have an object with settings which have id references to elements, like this:

```
(function (Erasmus, $, undefined) {
    var settings = {
        Agreement : {
            SourceUniversity: "#scrUni",
        }
    };
    Erasmus.Settings = settings;
})(window.Erasmus = window.Erasmus || {}, jQuery);
```

Now all select inputs are select2 and after initializing everything I bind the change events for the input like this:

```
(function (Erasmus, $, undefined) {
    var student = {
        BindPageControls: function () {
            $(Erasmus.Settings.Agreement.SourceUniversity).on("select2:select", function (selected) {
               console.log(selected); 
        });
      }
    };
    Erasmus.Student = student;
})(window.Erasmus = window.Erasmus || {}, jQuery);
```

Now the problem is that if I bind with:

```
$(Erasmus.Settings.Agreement.SourceUniversity).on(...
```

It binds to a different object (original input?) instead of the select2 input and wont trigger events, but if I bind like this:

```
$("#srcUni").on(...
```

It works all fine. Why is there a different reference fetched by JQuery when passing pure string and string as variable?

JQuery version 3.2.1, select2 version 4.0.4

Comment: There is a mistake: Erasmus.Settings.SourceUniversity instead of Erasmus.Settings.Agreement.SourceUniversity

Comment: Fixed as per comment, just a typo on my end, the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example from your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#srcUni').select2({
      placeholder: 'Select an option',
      width: 'resolve',
     dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
     allowClear: 'true',
  });

  Erasmus.Student.BindPageControls();
});

(function (Erasmus, $, undefined) {
    var settings = {
        Agreement : {
            SourceUniversity: "#srcUni",
        }
    };
    Erasmus.Settings = settings;
})(window.Erasmus = window.Erasmus || {}, jQuery);

(function (Erasmus, $, undefined) {
    var student = {
        BindPageControls: function () {
            $(Erasmus.Settings.Agreement.SourceUniversity).on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
            console.log("select item: ",data); 
        });
      }
    };
    Erasmus.Student = student;
})(window.Erasmus = window.Erasmus || {}, jQuery);
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select id="srcUni">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```